# Db versioning/new changes with loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback

My service is built using Node + Loopback + Mongo.
I would like to drop the db at the startup if and only if at least one of the following two asserts is true:

- any model schema has changed (note that I cannot use isActual() because that's usable only with relational DBs)
- new data has been added/removed from the default data-set definition files (data folder)

I'm currently versioning the db using a custom logic comparing version table and a version unique var but I wonder if there is an easy way to check the two asserts above.

Any idea? Ty